# Expressjs and Body-parser Posting Articles

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

```
app.post("/article/add", function(req, res) {
  let article = new Article();
  article.title = req.body.title;
  article.author = req.body.author;
  article.body = req.body.body;

  article.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    } else {
      res.redirect("/");
    }
  });
});
```

How can I change this and add articles in a similar way. I mean I cant create other ways to make it but I know there are lots of ways to post articles.

Comment: It's very unclear what are you trying to ask, please refer to [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @SuleymanSah neden cevaplarını sildin?

Comment: @SuleymanSah why did you deleted your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean, how to refactor your code in a better way, I would suggest these:

1-) use destructuring to parse req.body like this:

```
app.post("/article/add", function(req, res) {
  const { title, author, body } = req.body;
  let article = new Article({ title, author, body });

  article.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    } else {
      res.redirect("/");
    }
  });
});
```

2-) use async await syntax:

```
app.post("/article/add", async function(req, res) {
  const { title, author, body } = req.body;
  let article = new Article({ title, author, body });

  try {
    article = await article.save();
    res.redirect("/");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }
});
```

Comment: @AlpErenGül if the answer helps you, please acccept it as answer.

Comment: I couldnt try because I cannot make a validation with express-validator

Comment: @AlpErenGül you should ask a new question if you have a different one.